# Random timing for Opacity + Random movement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create random movement of a div (successful), tied with random opacity changes (partially successful). I've put together the following by mashing together two separate scripts into one.

The opacity changes only after each movement of the div. Ultimately I'd like to get the opacity to work independent of the movement. Any help would be appreciated!

I have it in [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/D2mZV/3/), or:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="a"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#container {height:500px;width:100%;}

div.a {
   width: 284px;
   height:129px;
   background:url(http://www.themasterbetas.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/aliens.png);
   position:fixed;
 }
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    animateDiv();
    runIt();
});

function makeNewPosition($container) {
    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    $container = ($container || $(window));
    var h = $container.height() - 50;
    var w = $container.width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh, nw];
}

function animateDiv() {
    var $target = $('.a');
    var newq = makeNewPosition($target.parent());
    var oldq = $target.offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    $('.a').animate({
        top: newq[0],
        left: newq[1]
    }, speed, function() {
        animateDiv();
    });
}

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {
    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

    var speedModifier = 0.1;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);

    return speed;
}

function runIt() {
    var $fading = $('.a');
    $fading.fadeTo("fast", Math.random(), runIt);
}
```

Comment: Did you want for opacity to animate *along* movement? Like [this altered example of yours](http://jsfiddle.net/D2mZV/4/)?

Comment: @SamuelLiew: That's true, but maybe he meant, to not work as is because it only changes when movement is put and then it moves again. His current example works as a series of move > opacity > move > opacity > ... While it could be move+opacity > move+opacity... We can't be completely sure what OP means.

Comment: @SamuelLiew: BTW OP also says: *...random movement of a div, tied with random opacity changes...* So there is a bit of a paradox.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses folks... I am looking for opacity to change independently. I'd like it to happen randomly. @RobertKoritnik has it close enough if I can't get complete randomness (thanks, BTW!).

Comment: @leftside Look at my Last answer

Comment: @leftside: so it seems that you'd like to have two separate animations running in parallel. One for movement and another for opacity. And they have different individual step durations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make them animate independently all you need is to apply the animations on different elements. I've created another div (*.wrapper*) that changes its position, while its child (*.a*), changes its opacity.

Here's the new HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <div class='a'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D2mZV/6/)

Comment: Here was the answer all along! Thanks @Itay, this works in FF23 and Chrome, and Safari! This is great, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/D2mZV/8/)

I've randomized the fade speed, as well. I think lots more could be done with this, including randomizing the easing effect, some colored lights at the bottom and the movement speed. Overall, this is a pretty slick little demonstration!

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    animateDiv();
    makeItSo();
});

function makeNewPosition($container) {
    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    $container = ($container || $(window));
    var h = $container.height() - 50;
    var w = $container.width() - 50;
    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
    return [nh, nw];
}

function animateDiv() {
    var $target = $('.warp');
    var newq = makeNewPosition($target.parent());
    var oldq = $target.offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);
    $target.animate({
        top: newq[0],
        left: newq[1]
    }, speed, function () {
        animateDiv();
    });
}

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {
    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);
    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;
    var speedModifier = 0.1;
    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);
    return speed;
}

function makeItSo() {
    var $fading = $('.ufo');
    $fading.fadeTo((Math.random() * 400), Math.random(), makeItSo);
}
```

**CSS**

```
div#container {
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
}
div.ufo {
    width: 284px;
    height:129px;
    background:url(http://www.themasterbetas.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/aliens.png);
    position:fixed;
}
div.warp {
    width: 284px;
    height:129px;
    position:fixed;
}
```

**Markup**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="warp">
        <div class='ufo'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Moving on Chrome but not on FF 23.

Comment: yes! @DevlshOne, that's about exactly what I'm looking for! I also checked on FF 23, there's no movement there... here's hoping though!